# Accessing External Objects in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

So far, I know that there are certain ways to access external objects in JavaScript, as I listed below

1. Through default JS scoping rule, if function A has function B inside, scripts in B will have access to variables owned by function A and any functions that enclose function A
2. Through `this` keyword: Simple function call to a function declaration B, `this` inside function B will have access to the global context.
3. Through global objects, such as `GLOBAL` in NodeJS and `window` in JS running in web browser

I would like to remove external references for function B, and say I managed to do something with the 3 options above. Is there any way I could use to access external objects other than those 3 ways?

Comment: Whats fundamental to all of these are scopes and closures. Do some research on how frameworks like Angular, Ember and Durandal handle objects. I suggest having some top level "namespace" objects to organize your code in.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like

```
var myApp = (function(window, $, ...lib references) {
  // everything defined in this scope will not clash with things defined in global

})(window, jQuery, lib2, lib3, lib4, ...other libs);
```

Also try reading about "javascript design patterns"

read this:
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/